# Is there a way to validate hAtom microformat?

Tags: validation, microformats

I have implemented [hAtom microformat](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom) on my blog.  At least, I think I have, but I can't find any validator (or any software that uses hAtom) in order to determine if I have done this correctly.  A [Google search for "hatom validator"](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=hatom+validator&btnG=Search) currently doesn't return anything useful.  Does anyone know of a way to confirm that it is implemented correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Convert it to Atom](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom#Implementations), [validate Atom](http://feedvalidator.org/) and manually check if it contains all data you expected.

There's open-source [hCard validator](http://hcard.geekhood.net/). Maybe someone could adapt it to validate hAtom as well…

Answer (score 9):

How about [Optimus](http://microformatique.com/optimus/)?

Otherwise, you can slow-validate it by adding it to the list of [hAtom examples in the wild](http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom-examples-in-wild). Occasionally someone will go through them and move the bad ones to the list of "Examples with some problems."

Answer (score 0):

You might find these useful

http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom#Examples

http://microformats.org/wiki/hatom#Implementations